# How does highstock represent the amount of point that is bigger than screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

*I cannot understand the behavior of data grouping/representation in highstock (highcharts). Given questions are related, and maybe enough to answer only one of them. But I separated them to make myself clearer.*

If we have 2000 points, screen resolution width is 1024px, and '**dataGrouping**' **is disabled**. (In area chart, or line chart).

1. How does highstock represent those points?
2. Is highstock still grouping points?
3. If **dataGrouping** is enabled and **groupPixelWidth** is set as 1, doesn't that mean it shows 1 grouped point per pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Those points just overlap.
2. No, if `dataGrouping` is disabled, points are not grouped.
3. Not exactly, as we can read in the API, that is `the approximate pixel width of each group`.

You can check the number of points in the example below and how their graphics are located.

---

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mnt9gxoc/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.dataGrouping.groupPixelWidth

Comment: Can you also share an explanation or the algorithm of how this grouping works to I understand what is hidden behind this 'approximate'?

Comment: Hi @befev, Sure, you can check `DataGrouping` source code: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/ts/parts/DataGrouping.ts and search for `groupPixelWidth`.